# Decompiled C# Project Config File

Tags: c#, sql, decompiler

I work for an engineering company who had a software engineer who has left. He designed software for the company but the source code cannot be found. I have decompiled the exe and have got it nearly running. My last issue (I hope) is that the connection string for the database is stored in an XML config file and when the project was created from the decompiler a config was not included.

My question is How do I add the config file so the decompiled project will use it? Or is it possible?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 if that makes a difference.

Comment: configs are not part of the compiled source (and thus wouldn't be included int he decompiled output) - there should have been a `web.config` or an `{appname}.exe.config` in the output folder.

Comment: D Stanley I have the original file which I am looking to add to the decompiled project. It is {appname}.exe.config, how do I reference it it the project?

Comment: Daniel A. White, no its not encrypted I have source code and able to edit but cannot connect to database as it isnt looking for config file with connection string

Comment: You don't explicitly add it to the project. By operation, a .NET executable will automatically look for a file by the name of appName.exe.config at startup.

Comment: From this point forward, be sure to put your code into some sort of source code control software such as TFS or SVN, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the connection string data is stored the `app.config` file, when the application is compiled this turns into the `myapplication.exe.config` file.

If you have the `<appname>.exe.config` file, you could just copy the contents with the connections string details into your own the `app.config` file in your project.

If your project does not have an app.config, simple right click the project in the Solution Explorer and choose Add Item and select "Application Configuration File".